# Is there a way to remove roads from the bike network which lead into residental streets for example?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I'm trying to create a graph to display all cyclign routes in a specific order. I then want to use these routes to create a database for generating cycling routes. The bike network from osmnx includes a lot of road/segmnets which i don't need. Therefore, i have the question if it is possible to reduce the complexity and remove some of the roads.

That's how i fetch the data:

```
ox.graph_from_bbox(lat1, lat2, lng1, lng1, network_type='bike', simplify=True)
```

in order to reduce the complexity I want to remove some unwanted road segments which aren't useful for cycling routes.

Image: (can't post a image right now) [Some of the unwanted "roads" are circled red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jJvQ.png)

Is there a way to remove them?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can remove any graph edge (or set of edges) you want, just like you would from any networkx graph. Or you can use a custom_filter with OSMnx when querying to get the exact network infrastructure you desire in the first place.